# How to achieve resizing of UITableView cells like instagram?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to be able to resize an UIImageView according to the size of the image which is in aspect fit.

and also i need to be able to resize the cell that the image is contained in.

A example would be the instagram app, they have different size images yet the cells are sized appropriately?

Comment: Use uicollectionview instead of uitableview

Comment: you can achieve it by dynamic calculation of its content.

Comment: can you create a resixable view ? if yes then make it content view subview of your table view cell. Get height of custom view and return from heightFromRow.

Comment: Where you able to solve this? I'm trying to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use auto layout when creating your table view cells
2. Set the table view rowHeight to equal`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.
3. Set the`estimatedRowHeight` or implement the height estimation delegate method.

You need to adopt the dynamic cell height. Now that cell will automatically determine its height from its content view subviews, make sure you have set your auto layout constraints carefully. Set content mode of UIImageView to aspect fit.

Below are some links to follow:
1. [Rey wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87975)

2. [Site Point](https://www.sitepoint.com/self-sizing-cells-uitableview-auto-layout/)

Comment: How would i go about doing autolayout for a UIView that is inside the cell and on top of the UIView has all the other objects, such as images, uibuttons, labels, etc.

Comment: this is how it looks on my storyboard http://imgur.com/owa0WE9, the white backgorund is a UIView, the grey one behind it is the cell's content view

Comment: Its pretty simple. Just give the constraints to the all subviews. And for the imageview set its leading, trailing, top and bottom from its superview. Make sure you have changed its intrinsic content size. I believe this is already well explained in the given links.

Comment: can you help me? i cant seem to get it. heres my storyboard http://www.filedropper.com/main_11

Comment: So i got the autolayout. And i also set in viewdidload the esitimated row height and also the rowheight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension. 

now the cell is extremely tall. no where near the height of the uiimageview

Comment: can you take a look at what i have so far?